# Root path in css (Jekyll)

Tags: css, path, jekyll, relative-path

I use variable {{ root_url }} to access root path (/) of my website (Jekyll). For eg. I can use it to include the path of external css file.

```css
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ root_url }}/css/main.css">
```

However in my css/main.css, I cant access {{ root_url }} for eg.

```
input {
    background: url(/{{ root_url }}/img/search-icon.png);
}
```

The image is not displayed as {{ root_url }} is not accessible inside css. How can I access {{ root_url }} inside css?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a relative path. Since CSS is in a subfolder one level deep, then you could do this:

```
input {
    background: URL(../img/search-icon.png)
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. The front matter in scss does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Only file with front matter are Liquid processed by jekyll.

If you want to use liquid in a css, you must add a front matter (even empty) in your `css/main.css` :

```
---
# this is an empty front matter that instruct jekyll
# to process this file with liquid
---
input {
    background: url(/{{ root_url }}/img/search-icon.png);
}
```